# Odoo header buttons missing

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

I'm having a problem with the create button appearing in tree view. Neither does the next or previous buttons appear in the form view. However, the data is being retrieved from the database.

[Tree form with missing buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l2F1.gif)

The module I'm trying to make is an extended module of the human resource module, like the included HR attendance module. The extended module doesn't inherit anything and security hasn't been added yet. Only a menu item is added to the main module.

A module I previously created by inheriting the main HR module created the buttons as expected.

[Expected outcome(different module)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4bUR.gif)

training.py:

```
from openerp import fields, models, api

class ew_training(models.Model):
  _name           = 'hr.training'

  var             = fields.Char(      string='variable')
```

training_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <!-- Main Submenu -->
    <menuitem id="menu_training_tree" action="action_view_training"
                  parent="hr.menu_hr_main" sequence="6"/>

    <record id="action_view_training" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Training</field>
      <field name="res_model">hr.training</field>
      <field name="view_type">tree</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_training_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">hr.training.tree</field>
      <field name="model">hr.training</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="var"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_training_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      ...
    </record>      
  </data>
</openerp>
```

**Please try avoid using the old API**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This should be work if you are trying to call differents views in differents actions.

The problem is not the button create, the problem is that you are not calling the tree view on your action `action_view_training`, try adding this line after `view_mode`:

```
<field name="view_id" ref="view_training_tree"/>
```

**EDIT**

To solve your case you only need to change in the `view_type`, you should use `form`:

```
<record id="action_view_training" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Training</field>
  <field name="res_model">hr.training</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

It should be work perfectly!!! I hope this could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've tried that, and I tried again, it didn't help. I also tried adding permissions, but to no avail. I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: I think I don't need tell you this, but did you update your module after save the changes?

Comment: Yes, I also tried updating the modules that it depends on as well as the modules it extends from just in case too. Also tried restarting the server.

Comment: It works! I would not have thought of that. I've been using view type forms strictly for form views. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just for Information.

in action `view_type` `tree` can be used when you want to create **hierarchical** view, It will not give you ability to create or update record. view of company structure in Odoo is the example of view type tree.

and `view_type` to `form` in action will allow you to create normal tree, form view with ability to Create, Update, Duplicate, Delete.

Hope this helps.